# Definition of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

There are something that I am not quite sure about the definition of basis.

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$, then the definition of basis says the vectors $v_1,...v_n$ form a basis of $V$ if they are linearly independent and span $V$.

Then if $$V= \{(\alpha,\beta) \in \mathbb{R}^2; \alpha = \beta\}$$  then is it still possible for me to say that the basis of this vector space is {$(1,0), (0,1)$} so that $\dim(V)=2$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ah, but your basis vectors have to be elements of the space that they span. The vector $(1,0)$ is not on the form $(x,x)$.

Comment: No, this is just a 1 dimensional space (a line) sitting in the plane. Remember the definition of coordinates - the unique coefficients that identify a point WRT a basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $(0,1) \notin V$ because $0 \neq 1 $. Now a basis would be $\mathcal{B} = \{(1,1)\}$.

By convention $B = \{v\}$, then $v$ is said to be linearly independent and if you take any $u \in V$ you will have that $$u = (\alpha, \beta) = \alpha (1,1)$$

then $(1,1)$ spans $V$.

Answer (score 3):

The vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are not in $V$ because $0\neq 1$, so no.

Answer (score 1):

These two vectors do not even "live" in your vector subspace $V$. So, they don't form a basis. Instead, note that $(1,1)$ forms a basis of $V$

Answer (score 1):

No, because $\{\{1,0\},\{0,1\}\}$ not only spans $V$, but also whole $\mathbb{R}^2$. $\{\{1,1\}\}$ is a basis for $V$ because it spans $V$ and only $V$. Therefore $\text{dim}(V)=1$.